# std::chrono supertype, function argument passing

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have

```
auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

and i want to pass it to a function using a general type for a time point. I do not want specify the resolution or type of clock used.

I've tried using

```
void my_function(std::chrono::time_point time_point);
```

but without success. Since apparently std::chrono::time_point isn't a type.

Comment: I mean, exactly what part of `time_point`'s interface are you planning to use that does not depend on the resolution or type of clock used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`std::chrono::time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) is a templated class, that needs at least a `clock` template parameter.

Either explicitly set the clock, like

```
void my_function(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> time_point);
```

Or you can make your function a template itself:

```
template<typename Clock>
void my_function(std::chrono::time_point<Clock> time_point);
```

In the last case you actually don't have to specify the template parameter when calling the function, the compiler figures it out for you:

```
my_function(now);
```

Comment: Yes, making the function a template seem so be the only option here. By the way, subtracting two different time_points with different clocks works just as it should (and addition of time_points does not, how would that be defined!?)